# How can I print both at the same time in C

Tags: c

**This is the bulletfire(move) code**

```
void fire(int bx, int by)
{
gotoxy(bx, by);
int a;
for (int i = bx; i >= MAP_X + 2; i--) {
    
    gotoxy(i+1, by);
    printf("  ");

    gotoxy(i, by);
    printf("<");
    Sleep(10);
    a = i;

}
gotoxy(a, by);
printf("   ");

}
```

**This is PlayerMove code**
"wasd" move and "n" bulletfire

```
while (1)
    {
        ch = '\0';
        bx = x - 1;
        by = y;
        if (_kbhit())ch = _getch();

        gotoxy(x, y);
        printf("        ");
        gotoxy(x, y + 1);
        printf("      ");
        gotoxy(x, y + 2);
        printf("      ");


        switch (ch)
        {
        case 'w':

            if (y > 2) y--;

            break;
        case 's':
            if (y < MAP_HEIGHT - 4) y++;
            break;
        case 'a':
            if (x > 6) x--;
            break;
        case 'd':
            if (x < MAP_WIDTH - 6) x++;
            break;
        case 'n':

            
            fire(bx, by);


            break;
        }
        if (y <= 4 && x <= 8) {
            shop();
            x = 70; y = 6;
            first();
        }
        else if (y <= 4 && x >= 50 && x <= 57) {

            first();
            dunjun();
            x = 70; y = 6;

        }
        gotoxy(x, y);
        printf("\\()()/");
        gotoxy(x, y + 1);
        printf(" \\  /");
        gotoxy(x, y + 2);
        printf("  \\/");
        gotoxy(1, 26);
        printf("%d, %d", x, y);


        Sleep(50);

    }
```

This is a code that shoots bullets horizontally when the n button is pressed.

Now, when the bullet button is pressed, the bullet is fired and the bullet moves, but the player's output is cut off.

I want to print the bullet firing animation and the player at the same time, how do I do that?

Comment: `while (1) { get_and_process_input(...); update_objects_and_screen(...); sleep(50); }`

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Your code fragments do not compile.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to make a command-line game that interacts with the console.

> Update both at the same time.

You will need to paint/update the entire canvas to achieve this effect.

Maintain a 2D array `char Map[MAP_HEIGHT][MAP_WIDTH]` and make changes to it depending on the user's input.

Then clear your console and print the contents of your `Map`.

**Suggestion:** [Consolidate and separate the input processing and canvas updation steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72590754/how-can-i-print-both-at-the-same-time-in-c/72591634#comment128228120_72590754).